# $f$ is defined in $\mathbb R$ , $f(f(x))=x^3$ then find $f(x)$ (not $f(x)=x^{\sqrt{3}} $)

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose that f(x) is defined in $\mathbb R $ and $f(f(x))=x^3$ 

 Does any function f exist which is not $ f(x)=x^{\sqrt{3}}$ ?

Comment: @Arthur $-(-x^{\sqrt{3}})^{\sqrt{3}}$ is not equal to $x^3$. You could take $f(x)=x^{-\sqrt{3}}$, but it is not defined at zero.

Comment: Do you want the function to be continuous? Because if not, then $x^{-\sqrt3}$ would work (which is what I meant to say above, @pregunton), with the addition that $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

There are many, even continuous ones.

A simple example is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-x&x<0\\-x^3&x\ge 0\end{cases} $$

Comment: what about functions not divided into 2 or more bounds?
(I mean simpler answers like the comment below the question)