# $f(f(x)) = x^3$, can $f$ be proved to be an odd function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Further if
$$f(f(x)) = g(x)$$
and we know that $g(-x)=-g(x)$ , i.e it's an odd function can we determine whether $f$ will be odd or not ?
Coming back to the original question, I first determined that $f($ is an *injective/one-one* function by,
$$ f(x) = f(y) $$
$$ \implies f(f(x)) = f(f(y)) $$
$$ \implies x^3 = y^3 $$
$$ \implies x=y$$
$ \therefore f$ is an *injective/one-one* function.
And since $f$ is injective it can't be an even function (except $f\equiv0$)

I couldn't further prove that $f$ will be odd, but what I noticed is; assuming that $f$ is an odd function, we find
$$ f(f(-x)) = f(-(f(x)) = -f(f(x)),$$
i.e., $g$ (in this case $g(x) = x^3$) is an odd function which is true. But it doesn't really prove that $f$ has to be an odd function.

Can $f$ be determined to be an odd function or is it impossible to prove, when $f(f(x)) = x^3$ or in the more general case of $f(f(x)) = g(x)$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2417452/42969 for a counterexample